# Displaying multi-line with multiple span dynamically

Tags: html, css

I am making some changes in UI recently and writing a html.erb file in Ruby.
As part of this, I want to understand how we can display multi-line text when there are multiple  in a single .

Example:

```
<div>
<span>
<span>"This is span 1. "</span>
<span>"This is span 2. "</span>
<span>"This is span 3."</span>
</span>
</div>
```

The way this displays the result is:

> This is span 1. This is span 2. This is span 3.

But based on the div size that I have, I want it to dynamically display the content of the spans, something like:

> This is span 1. This is span 2. This 
> is span 3.

OR

> This is span 1. This is 
> span 2. This is span 3.

Need help to understand what properties I can use in CSS to handle this.

Thank you.

I have already tried using some CSS properties to limit the size of Div by using display:inline-block & display:block. But this did not seem to work.

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. What you are describing is already the default behavior

Comment: @TemaniAfif When I create multiple spans in a single span, all the text of the spans is combined into one and a scroll-bar appears in the browser. I want to break the text at the size of the parent div and make the text multi-line.

Comment: *a scroll-bar appears in the browser.* --> no, at least not with the code you have provided. If it's the case, then you have some CSS you didn't show

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<div class="container">
    <span>
    <span>"This is span 1. "</span>
    <span>"This is span 2. "</span>
    <span>"This is span 3."</span>
    </span>
</div>
    
.container {
   display: block;
   width: 10rem;
   text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Usually "try this" is bad answer. It is unclear what is your answer. Why did you use `text-align: justify;`?